# In HTML, can I have text that falls back to an image when fonts are missing?

Tags: html, fonts

I want to make a submit button like

```
<input type="submit" value="→"/>
```

however I am not confident in the user having a font installed that covers →. I would like to use text where possible so that it is more consistent with the rest of the page, but replace the text with an image of an arrow when necessary.

Is there a way to test whether a glyph for a particular character is available?

Comment: Just with HTML no. Personally I would suggest you don't try to do such a thing. Either use the image always, or expect people who don't have the font to have problems. Note that with HTML5 you can now easily load a font and you could use that to load a font that includes that character. On the other hand, that won't anyway work on text based browsers (i.e. lynx).

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no such mechanism in HTML – you can specify a text alternative to an image (via the `alt` attribute in an `img` element), but not vice versa.

In practice, with a character like “→”, the main problem is not the presence of glyphs (it is hard to find a computer that does not have any font that covers “→”), but their quality. In many fonts, “→” is thin and small, thus unsuitable for use in a button. In some fonts, like Calibri, it is oddly shaped. And it is not that useful to try to make the character match the rest of the page typographically, since here “→” would be used as a standalone symbol rather than a text character.

Thus, it is probably best to use an image, e.g.

```
<button type=submit><img src=arrow.png alt=Forward></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at this project you should be  able to write the arrow and if the div width/height is the wrong size then assume the font doesn't exist, or use the code for a specific font and if that doesn't exist then use your image

http://www.lalit.org/lab/javascript-css-font-detect/

It can be done with javascript but not html.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<input type="submit" value="&#8594;"/>
```

Comment: Alternatively, I found a website with many other arrows that have that ampersand code.  [arrow code website](http://character-code.com/arrows-html-codes.php)